What is the best technique for precision cutting nickel foil?
I have a project where I need to cut small text at about 0.5 mm of precision on a nickel foil that is about 0.1 mm thick. So, I am looking for the best machine/technique to do it.
I know that nickel has a thermal conductivity of about 90 W/(m·K), so I guess diode or CO2 laser cutting would not be too bad with the right one. For now, this is my best option, but I want to hear other opinions on other possible ways.

A CO2 laser has a wavelength of around 10000nm. Lots of materials absorb this frequency like plywood, silicone, glass, and acrylic. However metal does not absorb this frequency very well. A better solution is to use a fiber laser or diode laser in the near infrared (NIR) wavelength around 900nm (0.9um).
This research paper shares the absorption spectrum for nickel. It shows high absorption at the NIR 0.9um wavelength.
Then you will need sufficient power and a narrow enough focus to heat the metal above its melting or burning point (depending on the cutting gas being used). For more information on this I recommend shopping around for cnc laser systems that cut similar or greater thicknesses of similar metal like stainless steel.

